# Creating a word scrambler but it won't work, need help as a beginner

Tags: python, cpu-word, scramble

Beginner python coder here, keep things simple, please.

So, I need this code below to scramble two letters without scrambling the first or last letters. Everything seems to work right up until the `scrambler()` function.

```
from random import randint
def wordScramble(string):
    stringArray = string.split()
    for word in stringArray:
        if len(word) >= 4:
            letter = randint(1,len(word)-2)
            point = letter
            while point == letter:
                point = randint(1, len(word)-2)
            word = switcher(word,letter,point)
    ' '.join(stringArray)
    return stringArray
def switcher(word,letter,point):
    word = list(word)
    word[letter],word[point]=word[point],word[letter]
    return word
print(wordScramble("I can't wait to see how this turns itself out"))
```

The outcome is always:

`I can't wait to see how this turns itself out`

Comment: What output you are expecting from this input?

Comment: Please do not use `string` as a **variable name** as it is a reserved name as a *Python module*

Comment: You say everything works until the scrambler() function... but there is no scrambler() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are a beginner, I tried to change your code as little as possible. Mostly you are expecting changes to `word` to change the contents or your list `stringArray`. The comments mark the changes and reasons.

```
from random import randint

def wordScramble(myString): # avoid name clashes with python modules
    stringArray = myString.split() 
    for i, word in enumerate(stringArray):   # keep the index so we can update the list
        if len(word) >= 4:
            letter = randint(1,len(word)-2)
            point = letter
            while point == letter:
                point = randint(1, len(word)-2)
            stringArray[i] = switcher(word,letter,point)  # update the array
    return ' '.join(stringArray)   # return the result of the join

def switcher(word,letter,point):
    word = list(word)
    word[letter],word[point]=word[point],word[letter]
    return ''.join(word)  # return word back as a string

print(wordScramble("I can't wait to see how this turns itself out"))
```

Comment: This is really bad, as you didn't point out the issue with using `string` as a variable name, also you falsely mention `array` whereas it should be `list` in **Python**

Comment: Since he's not importing `string`, there's no problem with using it as a variable name. There are so many modules that it's simply not practical to suggest people refrain from using *any* of them in their own programs.

Answer (score 0):

Because there *had* to be a cleaner (and better documented) way to do this:

```
from random import sample

def wordScramble(sentence):
    # Split sentence into words; apply switcher to each; rejoin into a sentence
    return ' '.join([switcher(x) for x in sentence.split()])

def switcher(word):
    if len(word) <= 3: # Don't bother if not enough letters to scramble
        return word

    # Pick 2 positions from interior of word
    a,b = sorted(sample( xrange(1,len(word)-1), 2 ))

    # Re-assemble word with out 2 positions swapped using bits before, between & after them
    return word[:a] + word[b] + word[a+1:b] + word[a] + word[b+1:]

print wordScramble("I can't wait to see how this turns itself out")
```